# How to make View Smaller Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have been googling around how to make view/page layout smaller on Tableau, but I could not find it. I am not sure what I did but I want make everything smaller like what it is used to be.

How can I make view/page layout smaller on tableau, ctrl + '-' is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually has to do with the Windows Screen Scaling.  Set it back to 100% and you may need to restart Tableau.

Comment: It was windows 10 update, and then Tableau emailed us about tableau update after that, they fixed issue. Thank